# Weird behaviour c++ for switch statement

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I have been looking at this piece of code for the last 3 hours and I am pretty stuck. I appreciate any help, thank you.

file: UnsortedType.h

```
#include "ItemType.h"
class UnsortedType{

public:
    UnsortedType();
    void RetireveItem(ItemType& item, bool& found);
    bool InsertItem(ItemType item);
private:
    int length;
    ItemType info[MAX_ITEMS];
};
```

file: UnsortedType.cpp

```
#include "UnsortedType.h"
#include <iostream>

UnsortedType::UnsortedType() {
    length = 0;
}

void UnsortedType::RetireveItem(ItemType& item, bool& found) {

    bool moreToSearch = true;
    int location = 0;
    found = false;

    moreToSearch = (location < length);

    while (moreToSearch && !found) {

        switch (item.ComparedTo(info[location])) {
            case LESS:
                location++;
                moreToSearch = (location < length);
                break;
            case GREATER:
                location++;
                moreToSearch = (location < length);
                break;
            case EQUAL:
                found = true;
                break;
        }
    }

    if (found) {
        item = info[location];
        std::cout << "Item " << item.getValue() << " has been retrieved." << std::endl;
    }

    else {
        std::cout << "Item " << item.getValue() << " has NOT found and has NOT been retrieved."
    }
}

bool UnsortedType::InsertItem(ItemType item) {

    if (length == MAX_ITEMS) {
        std::cout << "List is Full!" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Item " << item.getValue() << " has not been added." << std::endl;
        return false;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Item " << item.getValue() << " added successfully." << std::endl;
        info[length] = item;
        length++;
        return true;
    }
}
```

file: ItemType.h

```
const int MAX_ITEMS = 40;
enum RelationType{LESS,GREATER,EQUAL};

class ItemType{

private:
    int value;

public:
    ItemType();
    ItemType(int value);
    RelationType ComparedTo(ItemType otherItem);
    void Initialize(int value);
    void printItem();
    int getValue();
};
```

file: ItemType.cpp

```
ItemType::ItemType(){
    this->value=0;    
}

ItemType::ItemType(int value){
    this->value = value;
}

RelationType ItemType::ComparedTo(ItemType otherItem){

    if(value < otherItem.value){
        return LESS;
    }

    if(value == otherItem.value){
        return EQUAL;
    }

    if(value < otherItem.value){
        return GREATER;
    }    

}

void ItemType::Initialize(int value){
    this->value = value;
}

void ItemType::printItem(){
    std::cout << "Item Type: " << this->value <<std::endl;
}

int ItemType::getValue(){
    return this->value;
}
```

Please note: In the above code, I have ommited some code parts that I think that are not relevant. Therefore if you copy / paste the code and run it may require some include statements ( like iostream ) and so..

Now here is the question:

When I run the main like this:

```
UnsortedType unsortedType;

bool item3found = false;
ItemType item3(3);
unsortedType.InsertItem(item3);
unsortedType.RetireveItem(item3, item3found);

bool item1found = false;
ItemType item1(1);
unsortedType.InsertItem(item1);
unsortedType.RetireveItem(item1, item1found);

bool item2found = false;
ItemType item2(2);
unsortedType.RetireveItem(item2, item2found);
```

There are no problems.

The output is:

```
Item 3 added successfully.
Item 3 has been retrieved.
Item 1 added successfully.
Item 1 has been retrieved.
Item 2 has NOT found and has NOT been retrieved.
```

However if I first add item1 and retrieve item1, then add item3 and retrieve item3, the switch statement suddenly stops working.

So this is the main file in the weird situation:

```
UnsortedType unsortedType;

bool item1found = false;
ItemType item1(1);
unsortedType.InsertItem(item1);
unsortedType.RetireveItem(item1, item1found);

bool item3found = false;
ItemType item3(3);
unsortedType.InsertItem(item3);
unsortedType.RetireveItem(item3, item3found);

bool item2found = false;
ItemType item2(2);
unsortedType.RetireveItem(item2, item2found);
```

While debugging the program I keep myself finding in: 
    while (moreToSearch && !found)
and the code does not go to ANY of the switch statements. Any idea?

This is the output in the weird situation:

```
Item 1 added successfully.
Item 1 has been retrieved.
Item 3 added successfully.

RUN FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 1s)
```

Any help greatly appropriated, I am about to lose it!

Comment: I suggest continuing your debugging by adding a `default:` clause to your `switch` statement. Have it print out some ridiculous statement which includes the value of the variable that you are switching on.

Comment: Thank you, is there any way to mark question as solved?

Comment: @KorayTugay - If you think one of the answers is correct, select it as such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem looks to be in your `ComparedTo` member function:

```
RelationType ItemType::ComparedTo(ItemType otherItem){

    if(value < otherItem.value){
        return LESS;
    }

    if(value == otherItem.value){
        return EQUAL;
    }

    if(value < otherItem.value){
        return GREATER;
    }    

}
```

The comparison for the `GREATER` case doesn't appear to be correct.  For such a function, it would make sense that you don't allow a possible path through it that won't return a value (i.e., use `if`, `else if`, `else`).  Also, you might want to turn on all compiler warnings and treat them as errors; it would help to avoid a problem like this.

Comment: Nice eye! Copy-and-paste FTL.

Comment: Thank you, i was about to loose it. What does copy and paste ftl mean?

Comment: @KorayTugay I perhaps made a unwise assumption that you copy-and-pasted your `if` conditions and missed changing one of them.

Comment: Thanks, maybe... I can't really remember. Hours of going mad, experience +0.00001. Better than 0 I guess..

Answer (score 2):

In your `comparedTo` method, the last `if` statement is identical to the first - it should have `>` rather than `<`.

In fact, I'm surprised your compiler didn't complain of the possibilty of a code path not returning a value for that function. You may want to consider turning up the warning levels if that was the case - otherwise, *listen* to your compiler, it's generally not telling you stuff  you don't need to know :-)

I would have just returned `GREATER` unconditionally <sup>(a)</sup> at that point since, if it's neither less nor equal, that's the only remaining possibility. In other words, something like:

```
RelationType ItemType::ComparedTo (ItemType otherItem) {
    if (value < otherItem.value)
        return LESS;

    if (value > otherItem.value)
        return GREATER;

    return EQUAL;
}
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Actually, I probably would have overridden the `<`, `>` and `==` operators (and others if necessary) so I could just write `if (a < b)` in my code, rather than `if (a.comparedTo(b) == LESS)`. But that may be the next step in your education :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
RelationType ItemType::ComparedTo(ItemType otherItem){
    if(value < otherItem.value){
        return LESS;
    }
    if(value == otherItem.value){
        return EQUAL;
    }
    if(value < otherItem.value){         // !!!!
        return GREATER;
    }    
}
```

The `ComparedTo` function is incorrect. If `value > otherItem.value` it won't enter any of the `if`s and it will fall off without returning a value, causing undefined behavior.